# How to add foreign key to existing table that matches same type as shown by DataGrip?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I have a table `car`. I want to add a column to it `car.owner_id`. `owner_id` needs to point to my `user` PK ID table. `car.owenr_id` cannot be null, so every car must have an owner at creation.

I tried to add the `car.owner_id` key like so:

```
ALTER TABLE car ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS owner_id INT;

ALTER TABLE car
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id
FOREIGN KEY (owner_id)
REFERENCES "user" (id);
```

That added the column and it seems fine. However I am dealing with other foreign key columns that point to other tables. When I look at the explorer section in data grip, under foreign keys I see 4 of them now, the last one is the one I just added `owner_id`.

I don't understand why the one I added has a different icon:

[image]

As you can see the last key icon is different than the top 3.

Can somebody tell me why? Why do the top three foreign keys have a different icon than then one I added (last one at bottom)?

I want to create a foreign key to `user` table that is setup exactly like the other three and since I am not then one that set those up I am not sure how to make `car.owner_id` be the same type as the other three so it has the same icon.

Comment: Show us the postgres documentation URL you're reading for advice on how to define the FK column. Or the ALTER / CREATE TABLE statement you tried, with error messages.

Comment: If `car.owner_id` can not be null, then recommenden to use `ALTER TABLE car ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS owner_id INT NOT NULL`. Everything else you wrote is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The top 4 foreign-key icons indicate that you have some kind of OnDelete/OnUpdate set.
You can easily see and modify these using Datagrip's table modify feature:

right-click on table in database explorer -> `Modify Table`.

[image]

Comment: awesome. thank you. I checked that and they did add cascade delete rules on those keys. Now it makes sense.